# Error in the LIBNAME statement sas

Tags: excel, import, sas

I want to import a database of excel to SAS, I use the correct commands but SAS tells me the following errors:

ERROR: Connect:
ERROR:Error in the LIBNAME statement sas

```
libname dir  'E:\SAS\sessio2\dades';
proc import out=dir.m
datafile="E:\SAS\sessio2\dades\matrimonios.xlsx"
DBMS=excel 
replace;
RANGE="Hoja1$A1:AJ54"; 
getnames=yes;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

As Yick says, the error is in your `PROC IMPORT` statement.  Behind the scenes PROC IMPORT creates a LIBNMAE statement using the EXCEL engine.

Some things that might be wrong:

- If your version is prior to 9.1.3, I don't think you cannot read the
  new xlsx format.  Save the file in the old format and try again.
- Make sure you have specified the proper file and path.
- Make sure you have the range specified properly.
- The Range statement can be hinky.  Try specifying the SHEET= option
  instead.
- Make sure you have ACCESS/PC Files licensed.

Comment: Yes, I agree with @DomPazz on the range part. I generally don't like using the range statement in this case if I'm getting errors. Perhaps try importing your data set by commenting range out if you can. Or import a simpler data set to test your code.

Comment: @DomPazz My SAS version is 9.1.3, I've corrected the excel file to format .xls and it goes on with the same error.

Comment: @OriolPrat Check if the path in datafile= to your excel file is absolutely correct. And comment out the range statement if you can, just so that you can better isolate the error.

Comment: @OriolPrat Okay, have you changed `DBMS =` to .xlsx as well? One more thing as I've said before could be `range` statement, so see if you can comment it out with `*`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's your libname statement path that is incorrect or the version of your SAS. if you're using `datafile=` `"path.xlsx"`, then try using `DBMS=.xlsx` as well.

If that doesn't work, perhaps try changing `datafile=` from `.xlsx` to `.xls` I'm not sure which version of SAS you have.

But in 9.1.3 it's better to use `.xls` If your excel file is in `.xlsx`, just open it and save as 2003 `.xls` version. Your code seems to work fine on my computer but that's using my own excel file.

```
libname dir  'C:\sasdata';
proc import out=dir.m
datafile="C:\sasdata\sfosch.xls"
DBMS=excel 
replace;
*RANGE="Hoja1$A1:AJ54"; 
getnames=yes;
run;
```